# Automatically adding a colon to a string (e.g. 0800 to 08:00)

Tags: javascript, string, time, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to transform a string like "0800" automatically to "08:00".

So I thought that way: If I type in the running program 2 digits, after typing the third the colon should automatically appear between the second and third digit. Without refreshing or something.

Has anyone a solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="input" />​

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("input").onkeydown = function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode != 8 && this.value.length == 2) {
            this.value += ":";
        }
    }​
</script>
```

Working demo available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JpPT7/2/).

Comment: I think if you change the onkeyup into onkeydown, it would works better. Because if I keep holding down the button, the previous event just don't work so nice.